# How to pre-split a string for a hash in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, imagemagick, paperclip

In paperclip.rb (lib/paperclip.rb), in a block of comments regarding the `has_attached_file` method, on line 251 (in version 2.3.3), it reads regarding the `:convert_options` hash:

> NOTE: Strings supplied to :convert_options are split on space in order to undergo shell quoting for safety. If your options require a space, please pre-split them and pass an array to :convert_options instead.

I need to pass an option `-unsharp 1x2+1+.10` to Imagemagick, but can't figure out how / don't know what it means to pre-split the string.

I've tried:

```
:eightythumb => ['-antialias', '-thumbnail', '-unsharp 1x2+1+.10']
:eightythumb => ['-antialias', '-thumbnail', '-unsharp', '1x2+1+.10']
:eightythumb => ['-antialias', '-thumbnail', ['-unsharp', ' ', '1x2+1+.10']]
:eightythumb => ['-antialias', '-thumbnail', ['-unsharp', '+' '1x2+1+.10']]
```

**update**: have also tried

```
:eightythumb => ['-antialias', '-thumbnail', ['-unsharp', '1x2+1+.10']]
```

but they all get sent to Imagemagick from Paperclip as `'-antialias' '-thumbnail' '-unsharp' '1x2+1+.10'` which throws an error since `-unsharp` and `1x2+1+.10` aren't in the same string.

**final update:**

My error stemmed from -thumbnail requiring a dimension argument and had nothing to do with splitting the string. You can pass options to Imagemagick like this:

```
:convert_options => { :eightythumb => ['-thumbnail 80x80', '-antialias', 'unsharp 1x2+1+.10'] }
```

and they'll go through just fine.

Comment: Have you tried
:eightythumb => ['-antialias', '-thumbnail', ['-unsharp', '1x2+1+.10']]

Comment: @Tyr: Yes, comes through as `'-antialias' '-thumbnail' '-unsharp' '1x2+1+.10'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it means that it's looking for something like this:

```
:eightythumb => ['-antialias', '-thumbnail', '-unsharp 1x2+1+.10']
```

If you pass a single string, it will split it at whitespace characters.  If you pass it an array of strings, it will treat each as a complete option.

**Update:**  What happens if you add the escape characters yourself?  As in `'-unsharp\ 1x2+1+.10'`.

Comment: @bta: Sorry, should've put in that I tried that as well. I'll edit my question.

Comment: @bta: re your update: Comes through as `'-antialias' '-thumbnail' '-unsharp\' '1x2+1+.10'`

Comment: Let's back up a step here, we might be looking in the wrong place.  What is `:eightythumb` and how is it being used?  What does your call to `has_attached_file` look like?  Are you calling it directly, or through another method?

Comment: In everything that I have read, "pre-split the string" should mean "split it into an array of strings", similar to how Ruby pre-splits command-line parameters into the `ARGV` array.  Since that's not working for us here, there's likely something non-obvious that we're missing.  I haven't used paperclip myself, so I'll have to defer to someone who has more experience with this particular gem.

Comment: @bta: Thanks for your help, regardless. I appreciate the effort.

Comment: For future reference/searchers:

You can pass the options like this:

`:convert_options => { :eightythumb => ['-thumbnail 80x80', '-antialias', 'unsharp 1x2+1+.10'] }`

and they'll go through just fine.